# WAP to find the second largest number without using an array in java

Tags: java

I have received a question in my school programming assignment, which goes like this:
**Enter n count of numbers and find the largest and smallest among the lot. Also find the second largest number.**
Now, the main problem is the second smallest number part.. We have still not been taught arrays, so I want a solution to this question without arrays. This is what I have made till now, through this code, I am able to find the largest and the smallest number correctly, but I find the second smallest number part tough!

```
    import java.util.*;
class SecondLargest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println('\u000C'); //used to clear screen
        Scanner y=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of values to be entered");
        int n=y.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number 1");
        int num=y.nextInt();
        int max=num,min=num,temp=num;
        for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter number "+i);
            num=y.nextInt();            
            if(num>max)
            max=num;
            else if(num<min)
            min=num;
            
        }
        System.out.println("The largest number is "+max);
        System.out.println("The smallest number is "+min);
    }
}
```

Comment: just like you got input1, get input2 outside the loop, compare and assign them to min,max,min2. then in loop, compare the rest

Comment: Are you sure you are *not allowed* to use arrays? I mean it would make a lot of sense there to use them there and extra work is always good ig.

Answer (score 0):

Just make another variable like your min and max variables.

```
if (num<max && num >min) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create additional variable `max2` and shift previous `max` value when a new maximum is detected, or check if there is a value over `max2`:

```java
Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of values to be entered");
int n = y.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter number 1");
int num = y.nextInt();
int max = num, max2 = num, min = num;
    
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter number " + i);
    num = y.nextInt();
    if (num < min) {
        min = num;
    } else if (num > max) {
        max2 = max; // shift previous max to become the 2nd largest
        max = num;  // store max
    } else if (num > max2) {
        max2 = num;
    }
}
System.out.println("The largest number is     " + max);
System.out.println("The 2nd largest number is " + max2);
System.out.println("The smallest number is    " + min);
```

Comment: one small issue- if 1st input is the largest value, then that is set as 2nd largest as well.